# python 2.7 vs pyserial - no _port

Tags: usb, serial, python-2.x

I really have tried searching through all the forums. confusing.

The makers of Roboclaw wrote their test pythons scripts (and Roboclaw class) with Python 2.7. As of now, will NOT work with python v3.

So I'm stuck with that restriction.

When I run the basic script, it complains that "AttributeError: Roboclaw instance has no attribute '_port'".

Tech support just keeps telling people they need python 2.7.

What I did was "sudo apt-get install python-serial". No luck. Still same problem.

What I wanted to do was blow away ALL python and re-install just what I need.. but I read (?) that raspbian/debian uses python for things?

Anyway, here's what "dpkg --get-selections|grep python" says :

dh-python   install
libpython-stdlib:armhf  install
libpython2.7-minimal:armhf  install
libpython2.7-stdlib:armhf   install
libpython3-stdlib:armhf install
libpython3.5:armhf  install
libpython3.5-minimal:armhf  install
libpython3.5-stdlib:armhf   install
python  install
python-apt-common   install
python-minimal  install
python-serial   install
python2.7   install
python2.7-minimal   install
python3 install
python3-apt install
python3-minimal install
python3.5   install
python3.5-minimal   install


Any ideas?

Update (05/23/2018 @ 22:32 EDT):

I tried "sudo apt-get install python3-serial".  No luck.

Error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roboclaw_simplepwm.py", line 14, in 
    rc.ForwardM1(address,32)    #1/4 power forward
  File "/home/devchu/dev/roboclaw_python/roboclaw_python/roboclaw.py", line 647, in ForwardM1
    return self._write1(address,self.Cmd.M1FORWARD,val)
  File "/home/devchu/dev/roboclaw_python/roboclaw_python/roboclaw.py", line 311, in _write1
    self._sendcommand(address,cmd)
  File "/home/devchu/dev/roboclaw_python/roboclaw_python/roboclaw.py", line 126, in _sendcommand
    self._port.write(chr(address))
AttributeError: Roboclaw instance has no attribute '_port'

dpkg --get-selections|grep python 
dh-python                   install
libpython-stdlib:armhf              install
libpython2.7-minimal:armhf          install
libpython2.7-stdlib:armhf           install
libpython3-stdlib:armhf             install
libpython3.5:armhf              install
libpython3.5-minimal:armhf          install
libpython3.5-stdlib:armhf           install
python                      install
python-apt-common               install
python-minimal                  install
python-serial                   install
python2.7                   install
python2.7-minimal               install
python3                     install
python3-apt                 install
python3-minimal                 install
python3-serial                  install
python3.5                   install
python3.5-minimal               install

Comment: Try installing python3 version like so `sudo apt-get install python3-serial`. my guess is python-serial is the version compatible with python 2.7.

Comment: *Blowing* away python will render the OS fairly crippled when it comes to package management (been there, done that). one alternative way is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to create sandboxes containing only packages you require for your script as opposed to installing system wide. the link should have the installation procedure

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion.. (I'm new here going to update - no luck)..

Comment: might help checking [this](https://github.com/urill/pyroboclaw) out

Comment: What operating system you are using? I use _Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-04-18_ but cannot find `apt list *roboclaw*`. What is roboclow?

Comment: Hi... yes, I had briefly come across that unofficial Roboclaw library.

Comment: Roboclaw isn't part of any install... it's a motor controller that comes with some Python examples (written / tested in 2.7).  I don't the issue is that it's Roboclaw, but that how to get python 2.7 and correct working version of pyserial... but anyway here's the link to the exammples:  (may or may not work if you dont have a Roboclaw on USB because it probably wont get past the open() ):

Comment: http://downloads.basicmicro.com/code/roboclaw_python.zip

Comment: good idea though, I hadn't tried the 'unofficial' one - worth a try

Comment: crosspost ........ https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/15740/communicate-with-roboclaw-using-python-2-7-no-port-need-pyserial

Comment: https://github.com/urill/pyroboclaw